# Google Sheets Batch Update payload Limits

Tags: java, google-sheets

So I'm doing a batchUpdate for a lot of data. Personally, I'd love to upload all of it in one shot.
However, I suspect there might be some limitations as to the number of rows updated per call or the payload size. I couldn't find any documentation on this.

I want to know what is the best practice here. Do I assume there is no limit because of the lack of documentation? Or I set a conservative limit on my end (this could mean multiple calls for me).

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on read and write requests `per minute` and `per minute per user per project`.

It is unlimited on read and write `per day per project`.

You can check it on the documentation on [usage limits for the Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits):

| Quotas |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Read requests | Per day per project | Unlimited |  |  |
|  | Per minute per project | 300 |  |  |
|  | Per minute per user per project | 60 |  |  |
| Write requests | Per day per project | Unlimited |  |  |
|  | Per minute per project | 300 |  |  |
|  | Per minute per user per project | 60 |  |  |

Also, to check your personal quotas you can use the Cloud Console as mentioned on [Request a quota increase](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits#increase):

- [View your current quota usage and limits](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/quotas)

Comment: I've seen this before. This describes how many api calls I can make. In my case, a batchUpdate is ONE API call - but has many rows to be updated, I've tried with about 50,000 rows in one update and it worked. However, idk to where I can push that number :)